# Unable to publish pictures in Blog using Word 2010 to SharePoint 2013

Tags: blog, picture

I created a new site collection (`SharePoint 2013 on-prem, Community template`) and blog subsite. All out of the box, no customization. I open Word 2010, create a new Blog Post, register the blog site (`with SharePoint Blog Provider`), all works fine. Published a couple of text only blogs, it's all good. I create another blog with a picture in it and get an error.

> Word cannot publish the pictures in this post

[image: Error message from Word]

I've no odd characters in the site URL, only `/` and `:`

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on my environment and its working fine (Sharepoint 2013 on premise and word 2010)

Can you please check if you have document library called "Photos" in this blog site? Pictures get automatically saved here. If library is not there you might want to manually create this.

Comment: Yes, the Photos library is on the site and I'm site owner, so permissions are good. I've also got a 2007 farm here and I can blog with pics to that. I'm wondering if there's anything on the Web App. I'll a different web app on the 2013 farm to see if it works there.

Comment: also you can try creating blog through browser with image in it and see if you see any detailed error. (This way we will know, if its an issue with sharepoint or office)

Comment: Inserting a picture with the browser based blog works. The image is stored in the Photos library....bit of a head scratcher this one!

Comment: What do you see , if you click on MORE INFORMATION in message box. Are you seeing similar behavior for all the users? (Is it machine specific?)

Comment: More Information browses to a Microsoft Office community site that no longer exists. No very helpful I know! It's all users too.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to copy paste the image into the Word file, it fails.

But when I choose the `Insert > Picture` and load it from my drive it's published successfully.

So try with the  `Insert` option.

[image]

Comment: Somehow, even copy pasting the image also worked for me. Interesting find/drawback..every time I publish the blog,same photo gets uploaded again. It doesnt overwrite.

Comment: I tried the Insert > Picture option, it also fails. Also if you insert clip art, shapes, smartArt etc....all fails, except if you insert a table. I even tried to insert a picture in a table, that also fails with the same error.

Answer (score -1):

I created a new Photo library for the blog then went to the library settings, then Advanced Settings, I set this new library as the default Site Assets Library. I then renamed my old photo library "Old Photos" 
Did a test post, and it's working!

This hadn't been working since we migrated to SP 2013. The old photo library had migrated over as a document library instead of a photo library and lost the connection somehow.

Comment: I feel like this answers the question now.